# Simple PHP Person class modeling

Tags: php, mysql, database, oop, modeling

It's my first approach to OO PHP, I've created a Person class and I need to create Person objects by querying the database or by POST values. Then I need to save data to DB.

This is my code, I don't know if it's the correct approach. I need some advices.

```
class Persona {
    protected $id=NULL;
    protected $nome;
    protected $cognome;
    protected $cf=NULL;
    protected $indirizzo=NULL;
    protected $civico=NULL;
    protected $citta=NULL;
    protected $cap=NULL;
    protected $provincia=NULL;
    protected $nazione=NULL;
    protected $telefono=NULL;
    protected $fax=NULL;
    protected $cellulare=NULL;
    protected $email;
    protected $data_registrazione;
    protected $tipo_registrazione;


    public function createPersona($postData=NULL,$id=NULL,$email=NULL)
    {
        global $_CONFIG;
        if(is_array($postData) && isset($postData['nome']) && isset($postData['cognome']) && isset($postData['email']) && isset($postData['tipo_registrazione']))
        {
            $record=$postData;
        }elseif(isset($id)){
            $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$_CONFIG['tbl_persone']." WHERE id='".escape_string($id)."'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=1) return false;
            $record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        }elseif(isset($email)){
            $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$_CONFIG['tbl_persone']." WHERE email='".strtolower(escape_string($email))."'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=1) return false;
            $record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        }else{
            return false;
        }

        if(isset($record['cf'])) $record['cf']=strtoupper($record['cf']);
        if(isset($record['cap'])) $record['cap']=strtoupper($record['cap']);
        if(!isset($record['nazione']) && isset($record['prefisso'])) $record['nazione']=$record['prefisso'];
        $record['email']=strtolower($record['email']);
        if(!isset($record['data_registrazione'])) $record['data_registrazione']=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $vars=get_object_vars($this);
        foreach($vars as $key=>$value)
        {
            if(isset($record[$key])){$this->$key=$record[$key];}
        }
        if(!$this->validatePersona())return false;

        return true;        
    }

    protected function validatePersona()
    {   
        if(isset($this->id) && !validateID($this->id)) return false;
        if(isset($this->cf) && !validateCF($this->cf)) return false;
        if(isset($this->cap) && !validateCAP($this->cap)) return false;
        if(isset($this->email) && !validateEmail($this->email)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public function savePersona()
    {   
        global $_CONFIG;
        $vars=get_object_vars($this);
        foreach($vars as $key=>$value)
        {
            if($key!='id')
            {
                if(isset($this->$key))
                {
                    $columns.=$key.",";
                    $values.="'".escape_string($this->$key)."',";
                }
            }
        }

        if(!mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$_CONFIG['tbl_persone']." (".substr($columns,0,-1).") VALUES (".substr($values,0,-1).")"))
        {
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}

$p=new Persona();
if(!$p->createPersona($_POST)){
    echo 'Si è verificato un errore.<br />Riprova più tardi. [0]';
    exit;
}

if($p->createPersona(NULL,NULL,$_POST['email'])){
    echo 'Indirizzo email già registrato.';
    exit;
}

if(!$p->savePersona()){
    echo 'Si è verificato un errore.<br />Riprova più tardi. [2]';
    exit;
}
```

The second step is to create a dynamic HTML table with people data from my DB, now by procedural language I fetch the DB and create an array, then with a foreach construct I print the table, but I don't know how with OO language.

Thank you all

Francesco

Comment: Great work for a beginner. read about patterns, active record, table gateway, mapper. there are commonly accepted ways of doing what your trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to map database query results to an object, use `PDO` instead. The `mysql` driver is obsolete and is highly discouraged to use. Also, `PDO` is fully OOP. Read some tutorials online.
2. `protected $id=NULL;` You don't have to explicitly assign null to uninitiated properties. Also, if you know that a property is to be accessed from outside (i.e. via an object), make the property `public`: `public $id;` is just enough. The purpose of `protected` is if you want some properties to be available to classes that are derived from your main class ( = child classes).
3. Don't use the keyword `global`. Use a config class with constants or read the settings from an array that you include in a separate file.  You can pass that array to the class constructor.
4. If createPersona is your main method of construction, you can rename it to `__contruct` and thus simply do like this: `$persona = new Persona($_POST);`

Also write `null` instead of `NULL`, it's cleaner and slightly more efficient.

```
function __construct(Array $postData = array(), $id = null, $email = null) {

}
```

Comment: 1. I'll do It.
2. Uninitiated properties are null, so I don't have to explicit it, ok. I made them protected because I know one of the foundamentals of OOP is isolation, so I can preserve them from other code (I should use private properties in my simple case).
3. Ok, the array seems to be a simple and clear way to do this. I'm going to see how some libraries do this.
4. I know, but I need to return true or false if there's an error during mysql query or validation, so I changed it to simple public funcion.

Thank you for the advices, very helpful, if you have other advices I'm very interested

Comment: @TheEscapist Sure. You can actually trigger exceptions within the construct and thus have full control of validation. You can make a status property that you can check to see if things went okay during contruction: `if ($p->valid === true) { // things are okay}` Let me know if you need help with PDO as well :)

Comment: Ok but this means that I have to do a check everytime after construction, so I can easily switch validatePersona() to public and do the control whitout adding 'valid' property. Another solution (but tell me if It's correct and has sense) is to create a factory class that help me to construct a Person by ID, POST or EMAIL (or others if I need) with a  public function and only two arguments, the origin and the type. So in the Person class I've only the needed properties, a constructor that assign data, and the other relative functions.

Comment: @TheEscapist Exactly, you can create a factory class called `PersonaFabbrica`, let that one do the query stuff with PDO, then create `Persona` as a helper class.

Answer (score 0):

@silkfire @DevZer0 Ok, so I edited my previous code, what do You think?

```
class factoryPersona {  
    public function createPersona($origin,$by)  
    {  
        switch($by)  
        {  
            case 'post':  
                // get data from $_POST to $array  
                break;  
            case 'id':  
                // get data from DB to $array  
                break;  
            case 'email':  
                // get data from DB to $array  
                break;  
        }  
        $persona=new Persona($array);  
        if(!$persona->validatePersona())  
        {  
            // validation error  
            exit;  
        }  
        return $persona;  
    }  
}  

class Persona {  
    private $id;  
    private $nome;  
    private $cognome;  
    private $cf;  
    private $indirizzo;  
    private $civico;  
    private $citta;  
    private $cap;  
    private $provincia;  
    private $nazione;  
    private $telefono;  
    private $fax;  
    private $cellulare;  
    private $email;  
    private $data_registrazione;  
    private $tipo_registrazione;  

    public function __construct($array=null)  
    {  
        // assignments  
    }  

    public function validatePersona()  
    {  
        if(isset($this->id) && !validateID($this->id)) return false;  
        if(isset($this->cf) && !validateCF($this->cf)) return false;  
        if(isset($this->cap) && !validateCAP($this->cap)) return false;  
        if(isset($this->email) && !validateEmail($this->email)) return false;  
        return true;  
    }  

    public function savePersona()  
    {  
        // save person to DB  
    }   
}  

$persona=new factoryPersona;  
$persona=$persona->createPersona($_POST,'post');  
$persona->savePersona();
```